# Apache Commons Daemon procrun Access is denied on windows 7

Tags: java, windows, windows-services

i try to run the example for windows that comes with :

> commons-daemon-1.0.10-src\src\samples\ProcrunService.java

i complied it fine , but when i run the ProcrunServiceInstall.cmd im geting

> Access is denied

i running also as command like like this :

```
prunsrv //IS//ProcrunServiceJvm --DisplayName="ProcrunServiceJvm" --Startup=auto --Install=d:\dev\java\libs\commons-daemon-1.0.10-src\commons-daemon-1.0.10-src\dist\prunsrv.exe --StartMode=java --StopMode=java --Classpath=d:\dev\java\libs\commons-daemon-1.0.10-src\commons-daemon-1.0.10-src\dist\ProcrunService.jar --StartClass=org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main  --StopClass=org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main --StartMode=java --StartClass=ProcrunService --StartParams=start --StopMode=java  --StopClass=ProcrunService  --StopParams=stop
```

and error im getting :

```
[2012-11-10 12:03:29] [error] Unable to open the Service Manager
[2012-11-10 12:03:29] [error] Access is denied.
[2012-11-10 12:03:29] [error] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 8 (Failed to install service)
[2012-11-10 12:03:29] [error] Access is denied.
Access is denied.
Failed to install service
```

what is the problem here ? its my home pc where i have all the rights and control on the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running your command from a prompt with admin rights. Right-click on the CMD.exe icon and select "Run as administrator" to start it that way.

Comment: [Try this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/) or [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28WS.10%29.aspx). If you can't do either one, then you are not an administrator.

Comment: i am the administrator this is my home pc no one using but me

Comment: What version of Windows is it?

Comment: So what happens when you try to to start a command prompt as administrator (see earlier comments)?